# Jquery modal with complete HTML page written on-the-fly

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I got an admin interface with its proper CSS styles.

I'm wondering if there is a way in Jquery to open a modal with a complete HTML page written on-the-fly ?

My goal is to avoid conflicts with CSS from the admin interface by writting a whole new HTML page in this modal.

Modal content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
/* Modal specific CSS here */
</head>
<body>
/* Content here */
</body>
</html>
```

I know it's possible to load a specific URL in a modal, thus I try to avoid an extra HTTP request.

Comment: where is your modal code here?

Comment: I'm using the bootstrap snippet here : http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

I'm just wondering if it's possible to write a complete HTML page.

Comment: Koffee, have you tried iframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except from within an `<iframe>` (which requires an extra HTTP request), there is no way to have an extra `<html>` tag inside your original HTML page. Therefore your modal must be part of that original HTML page, and inherit the CSS.

The best answer I can think of (and also the one that is commonly used, eg in Twitter Bootstrap) for your case, is to create a modal div and **overwrite** the admin CSS with the modal's own CSS:

```
<div id="modal">
    Your modal content.
</div>
```

And in your CSS file:

```
#modal whatever {
    // Modal specific CSS
}
```

Comment: Yeah i though of it, it may be a pain in the ... but I guess I have no other choices. Thanks